# What is the correct way to write 'for ever more'?

Tags: phrases, orthography, spacing

I know that 'forever' is a word, and I know that 'evermore' is a word, but what is the correct way to write the phrase 'for ever more'? Is it 'forever more'? 'For evermore'? Or even *'forevermore'*, as a long shot? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The OED has both flavors:

- 1850 Tennyson *In Mem.* xxxiv, ― My own dim life should teach me this, That life shall live for evermore.
- 1872 Longf. *Christus Introitus* 46 ― Forevermore, it shall be as it hath been heretofore.

I myself would do the second; it goes with Poe’s *nevermore*.

Are you sure you need the *for* part?  Might *evermore* alone suffice?

> *From helm to sea they saw him leap,
>
>           As arrow from the string,
>
>   And dive into the water deep,
>
>           As mew upon the wing.*
>
> The wind was in his flowing hair,
>           The foam about him shone;
>   Afar they saw him strong and fair
>           Go riding like a swan. 
>     
>   But from the West has come no word,
>           And on the Hither Shore
>   No tidings Elven-folk have heard
>           Of Amroth evermore.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer! I think they are essentially the same, the _for_ is quite unwieldy. I was transcribing lyrics, though, and I was curious as to how this ought to be written. I think I prefer the second style as well, simply because of how ridiculous it looks.

Answer (score 5):

Edgar Allen Poe also used 'for evermore', famously in [*The Raven*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Raven).

> *Ah, distinctly I remember it was in the bleak December;
>
>   And each separate dying ember wrought its ghost upon the floor.
>
>   Eagerly I wished the morrow; – vainly I had sought to borrow
>
>   From my books surcease of sorrow – sorrow for the lost Lenore —
>
>   For the rare and radiant maiden whom the angels name Lenore —
>
>                  Nameless here for evermore.*

And while I'm here... ***NEVERMORE***. ;)

Comment: Incredible rhymes from dis guy